# C++ ошибка dependent name is not a type, prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type

Tags: c++

пишу бинарное дерево и наткнулся на очень непонятную мне ошибку, вот пример:

```
template<typename T>
class BinaryTree 
{
public:
    ...
private:
    ...
    struct Node
    {
        T value;
        Node* leftChild;
        Node* rightChild;
    };

    Node* copyTree(Node* node);
    ...
};

template<typename T>
BinaryTree<T>::Node* BinaryTree<T>::copyTree(Node* node)
{
    if (node == nullptr) 
    {   
        return nullptr;
    }

    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->value = node->value;
    newNode->leftChild = copyTree(node->leftChild);
    newNode->rightChild = copyTree(node->rightChild);
    return newNode;
}


warning C4346: 'Node': dependent name is not a type
note: prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Node'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Comment: зачем структуру Node вы объявляете внутри класса BinaryTree?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch а какой смысл объявлять ее снаружи?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, если для других целей класс не нужен, кроме как представление этого класса, лучше обьявлять именно внутри класса

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: Именно так и должно быть.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При использовании *квалифицированного* имени вложенного типа (т.е. имени вида `T::U`), когда наружный тип является *зависимым* (т.е. является шаблоном с неизвестным параметром), требуется указание ключевого слова `typename`.

В вашем случае: правильно не `BinaryTree<T>::Node`, а `typename BinaryTree<T>::Node`.

(Еще раз: это относится только к случаям, когда `T` - это параметр шаблона. Если же вы указываете *конкретный аргумент*, то `typename` добавлять не нужно. Например, `BinaryTree<int>::Node`.)

В данном примере важно то, что при определении функции-члена класса за пределами класса с использованием *классического* синтаксиса, тип возвращаемого значения ищется во внешней области видимости, а объявления параметров методов - сначала в области видимости класса. Поэтому при указании типа возвращаемого значения вы вынуждены использовать *квалифицированное* имя `BinaryTree<T>::Node` и, согласно правилу выше, добавлять `typename`. А вот в параметрах функции-члена класса можно свободно использовать *неквалифицированное* имя `Node`. То есть правильно

```
template <typename T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::Node* BinaryTree<T>::copyTree(Node* node)
```

Если же вам вдруг по какой-то причине захочется и в объявлениях параметров использовать квалифицированные имена типов, то и там будет применяться правило `typename`

```
template <typename T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::Node* BinaryTree<T>::copyTree(typename BinaryTree<T>::Node* node)
```

---

При использовании *нового* синтаксиса с `auto` и замыкающим типом возвращаемого значения, имя типа возвращаемого значения тоже сначала ищется в области видимости класса. Поэтому альтернативным вариантом будет

```
template <typename T>
auto BinaryTree<T>::copyTree(Node* node) -> Node*
```

т.е. в этом случае мы обходимся без квалифицированных имен для `Node` и, соответственно, без `typename`.

Comment: Подробный и грамотный рассказ

Comment: Соглсаен, хорошо написано. Но что имеется в виду под "*свободный* параметр шаблона"?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Я не хотел лезть в лишние побочные детали. Шаблон остается шаблоном, пока у него есть "незафиксированные" параметры. Т.е. `template <typename A, typename B> struct SomeTemplate` - это шаблон с двумя параметрами. Если я сделаю частичную специализацию `template <typename A> struct SomeTemplate<A, int>`, то в этой специалиазции я "зафиксировал" параметр `B` исходного шаблона, а параметр `A` оставил "свободным". А вот у специализации `SomeTemplate<double, int>` "свободных" параметров уже не осталось - все параметры явно указаны, т.е "зафиксированы".

Comment: @AnT Все, теперь понял.